# how to read through a directory for specific lines and output to a text file?

Tags: bash

How can I, in a bash script, read through a directory, parsing each file, which are like `foobar_plugin.py` and write out to one file everything that is in the lines, delineated by `'''    '''`

```
def foobar(self, args):
    '''Backup data to repository.'''
```

I am envisaging that the scripted output will be something like -

```
command foobar #pulled from the def line above#
write #pulled from between ''' and '''#

# goto next file; repeat#
command next_foobar
write #pulled again#
```

There are 13 foobar_plugin.py scripts to be read through, and 3 are named like `foobar_barfoo_plugin.py`. Not every `foobar_plugin.py` file will contain `def foobar(self, args):` so if not, it needs to process to the next plugin file.

***And each `foobar_plugin.py` contains a different descriptor between ''' and ''', and it is these descriptors that I'm wanting to data-mine.***

How can I do it please and output everything to one text file?

Comment: I think that you should take a look at [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) as it looks like you're trying to roll your own version of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about matching the output format exactly, you could use grep:

```
$ cat file
something else

def foobar(self, args):
    '''Backup data to repository.'''

blah blah blah
$ grep -rB1 "'''.*'''" .
./file-def foobar(self, args):
./file:    '''Backup data to repository.'''
```

`-r` is for recursive, and `-B1` is to also print the previous line

Comment: I'm sorry @user000001, I see that what was obvious to me wasn't to other folks, so I've refined my original question.

Answer (score 1):

To add a formating part from user000001, say you have these files :

```
$cat file1_plugin.py
something else

def foobar(self, args):
    '''Backup data to repository.'''

$cat file2_plugin.py
blah blah blah

def next_foobar(self, args):
    '''Backup other data'''
```

With that awk one-liner :

```
grep -B1 "'''.*'''" *_plugin.py | 
awk '$1~/def/{printf "command " ; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf $i" "; print $NF}
($1~/:/){printf "write " ; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf $i" "; print $NF"\n"}'

command foobar(self, args):
write '''Backup data to repository.'''

command next_foobar(self, args):
write '''Backup other data'''
```

In case you want to get rid of the single quotes :

```
grep -B1 "'''.*'''" *_plugin.py |
awk -v replace="'" '
($1~/def/){printf "command " ; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf $i" "; print $NF}
($1~/:/){printf "write " ; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {gsub(replace,"",$i); printf $i" "}; gsub(replace,"",$i); print $NF"\n"}'
```

**outputs**

```
command foobar(self, args):
write Backup data to repository.

command next_foobar(self, args):
write Backup other data
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm sorry @jeanrjc, I see that what was obvious to me wasn't to other folks, so I've refined my original question.

Comment: @boudiccas : The missing part is that you want to parse only files like `*_plugin.py` ? if so, just modify the grep part : `grep -B1 "'''.*'''" *_plugin.py`. If it's not that, please re-write your question with 2 files as an example, and the exact output you expect.

Comment: Yes, but also what I call, the 'file descriptor', i.e., between ''' and ''' is what I'm really looking for, in a range of *_plugin.py files.

Comment: @boudiccas : I edited, tell me what you expect as an output, and please, edit your question to make it clearer